# Google maps, formatting a string. (Removing apostrophes)

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, google-maps

I'm currently working on a google map and I have this code loading some content into the markers from a CMS.

```
function showMarker(index) {
    infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content + "</div>");
    infowindow.open(map, markers[index]);

    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());

    showAttractionInfo(index);
}
```

However, the issue at hand is if an apostrophe or quotations are put in via the CMS is will break the map and it will not display.

I need a way to format `markerData[index].content` before it is put into the map removing the apostrophes and quotations.

I tried using `replace` but it didn't work for me at all.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I've tried these solutions so far:

```
infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content.replace(/'/g, '') + "</div>");
```

---

```
    var description = markerData[index].content;
    description.replace(/'/g, '');
    infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + description + "</div>");
```

---

```
 var description = markerData[index].content;
            description.replace("'", "");
            infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content + "</div>");
```

---

```
var description = markerData[index].content;
            description.replace("'", "&#39;");
            infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content + "</div>");
```

---

```
var description = markerData[index].content;
            description.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
            infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content + "</div>");
```

---

Here's an example of one of the marker datas (WITH an apostrophe)

72 Drymen's Road, Bearden, Glasgow, G61 2RH

Comment: Please post the code you tried that didn't work -- there may just have been a typo or simple error.

Comment: Post an example of `markerData[index].content` so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: [You can use a bit of regex btw](http://jsfiddle.net/z92hano6/).

Comment: How do you set the content-property for the markers? I guess you  must encode the string on serverside, e.g. by using JSON

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert those double quotations to single quotes. Because in your line

```
infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + markerData[index].content + "</div>");
```

You have used double quotes to create string. Use something like this:

```
var modified = markerData[index].content.replace(/"/g, "'");
infowindow.setContent("<div class=\"map_marker\">" + modified + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
   function htmlCodes(s) {
       return String(s).replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
   }
```

codes are here: http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/htmlchrc.html